# Mirror Selected Faces Without Mirror Modifier

Tags: mesh, mirror, select

I currently want to delete the mesh which is covering the eye sockets so that I can place eyes in. Because it is a human, the topology selection needs to be symmetrical. When I try use a mirror modifier (with clipping enabled), my mesh stuffs up. So does anyone know how to select mesh on both sides of the face with only selecting one eye. Btw this is a high poly face so I can't just select and hope for the best.

Many Thanks
Liam

Comment: There is a Select Mirror option. Ctrl+Shift+M.

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete half of your mesh before mirroring? Enable the Auto Mirror add-on in User Preferences and try using that to mirror your object.